# php split string by <tr>

Tags: php, arrays, split

I've some tabular data which is fetched from database. Like,

```
<tr><td>key1</td><td>pair1</td></tr>
<tr><td>key2</td><td>pair2</td></tr>
<tr><td>key3</td><td>pair3</td></tr>
<tr><td>key4</td><td>pair4</td></tr>
```

I want to split them with `<tr>`(s), and want rows in an array.
ex.

```
$arr = ("<td>key1</td><td>pair1</td>", 
"<td>key2</td><td>pair2</td>", 
"<td>key3</td><td>pair3</td>", 
"<td>key4</td><td>pair4</td>");
```

I heard about `explode(',', $myString);`but it works with comma saperated string.

**Note** : Please don't suggest **DOM Parser**

Comment: try [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split)

Comment: @webeno I'm weak in regex please specify pattern ..

Comment: me too, sorry, otherwise I would have added it as an answer;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$out = array_filter(explode('</tr>', str_replace('<tr>','',$input)));
```

Comment: @user3710243 Great, lad i could help you

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
explode('<tr>', $myString);
```

You can explode every String with any pattern.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

But if you split with

```
<tr>
```

you still have the

```
</tr>
```

in your Array as String. You could also remove them by removing the last 5 Characters in every Array String.

Comment: the problem with that is that it will exclude the delimiter, so the array will not have the first `<tr>` in it...

Comment: You could loop trough all array items and add them to the beginning.

Comment: But expecting the array without having neither `<tr>` nor `</tr>`. removing `</tr>` will work but any clear solution ?

Comment: Another possibility could be to use a DOM Parser (i dont know your requirements) - but have a look at this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
<?php 

$arr ='<tr><td>key1</td><td>pair1</td></tr>
<tr><td>key2</td><td>pair2</td></tr>
<tr><td>key3</td><td>pair3</td></tr>
<tr><td>key4</td><td>pair4</td></tr>';
str_replace('<tr>','',$arr);
$rows = explode('</tr>',$arr);
 print_r(array_filter($rows));// arry_filter is used to remove the last null node.
?>
```